# Why doesn't the value a CALayer's "transform.scale" match its transform scale?

Tags: ios, uikit, calayer, catransform3d

Imagine you're trying to scale a layer and then later read that scale back out (for example: during an animation that's changing the scale).

```
let desiredScale = 0.5
layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(desiredScale, desiredScale, 1)
let readScale = layer.value(forKeyPath: "transform.scale") as? Double
print("scale: \(readScale)") // "scale: 0.6666666"
```

The scale value read out using `value(forKeyPath:)` will be close but not quite right!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because the value read out has something to do with the whole 3D scale (think in x, y, and z). Reading out the x or y scale specifically will return the right value:

```
let desiredScale = 0.5
layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(desiredScale, desiredScale, 1)
let wholeScale = layer.value(forKeyPath: "transform.scale") as? Double
let xScale = layer.value(forKeyPath: "transform.scale.x") as? Double
print("scale: \(wholeScale)") // "scale: 0.6666666"
print("scale: \(xScale)") // "scale: 0.5"
```

Comment: That was fun. By the way, you don't have to say `as? NSNumber)?.floatValue`. This is Swift, not Objective-C! Just `as? Double` will do.

Comment: @matt Learning lots today. Thanks!!